# Wordpress: Whatsapp sharing does not show the featured image as thumbail. Instead, it shows the favicon

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp

Link: https://www.rekhanisaraogi.com/2020/05/14/digitization-risk-assessment-it-audit/

Please help.

I am unable to find out the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a SEO plugin (Yoast SEO) and configured it and it got solved on its own. I believe the plugin overrode the header meta data to featured image.